# In Kotlin, is there any way to define method for a aliased type?

Tags: kotlin

Say I have a aliased type:

```
typealias Bitmap5x5 = Int
```

Is there any way to define method for this type, as if it's a real object? Like some constructor, methods? I have GB level amount of data, so I don't have enough RAM to box them in real objects. (I tried, turns out to be horrible)

I'd have some methods which can be use like this:

```kotlin
var bitmap1 = Bitmap5x5(1) // a white one
var bitmap2 = Bitmap5x5(0) // a black one
bitmap1.drawVerticalLine(0, 3) // draw a black line a on column 3
bitmap2.drawHorizontalLine(1, 2)
```

Currently I have a static helper class `Bitmap5x5Helper` to group some methods like this, but kind of ugly:

```kotlin
var bitmap1 = Bitmap5x5Helper.makeBitmap(1)
var bitmap2 = Bitmap5x5Helper.makeBitmap(0)
bitmap1 = Bitmap5x5Helper.drawVerticalLine(bitmap1, 0, 3)
bitmap2 = Bitmap5x5Helper.drawHorizontalLine(bitmap2, 1, 2)
```

If it is impossible to handle integer like this, is there any way to just define static method for it? So at least directly, without the "Helper"

`bitmap1 = Bitmap5x5.drawVerticalLine(bitmap1, 0, 3)`

Comment: Are the `drawXXXLine` methods going to change the `Int` value?

Comment: You could always just define an extension function on `Bitmap5x5` so you could call `Bitmap5x5.drawHorizontalLine(1, 2)`, but this would also allow you to use `Int` as the receiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a `value class`. `Bitmap5x5` can be written like this:

```
@JvmInline // if on JVM
value class Bitmap5x5(val value: Int) {
    fun drawVerticalLine(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): Bitmap5x5 { // I'm not sure what the parameters represent
        val newValue = value + arg1 + arg2 // imagine complicated calculations going on here
        return Bitmap5x5(newValue)
    }

    // fun drawHorizontalLine(...): Bitmap5x5 { ... }
}
```

Usage:

```
var bitmap1 = Bitmap5x5(1)
bitmap1 = bitmap1.drawVerticalLine(0, 3)
```

Note that you still have to write `bitmap1` twice to reassign `bitmap1`. This is unfortunately not possible to avoid while also satisfying the requirement of not boxing the integer. This wouldn't have been a problem though if `drawVerticalLine` doesn't mutate the thing on which it is called, and instead mutates some external state, like draws something on the screen or something like that.

Note that although it may seem like `Bitmap5x5(1)` "boxes" an integer, no boxing actually occurs here. Boxing only occurs for value classes [when it is necessary](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#representation) - for example, when you convert it to `Any`:

```
println(bitmap1) // boxing occurs here, otherwise an Int would be printed, which is not correct
```

For reference, here is the JVM bytecode that the three lines of code above generates:

```
   0: iconst_1
   1: invokestatic  #12                 // Method Bitmap5x5."constructor-impl":(I)I
   4: istore_0
   5: iload_0
   6: iconst_0
   7: iconst_3
   8: invokestatic  #16                 // Method Bitmap5x5."drawVerticalLine-SupUMkI":(III)I
  11: istore_0
  12: iload_0
  13: invokestatic  #20                 // Method Bitmap5x5."box-impl":(I)LBitmap5x5;
  16: astore_1
  17: getstatic     #26                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  20: aload_1
  21: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  24: return
```

Notice that `box-impl` is only called before calling `System.out.println`, and that `constructor-impl` returns an `int` (descriptor is `(I)I`). `constructor-impl` would have contained the code in the `init` block of the `value class`, but in this case, it's just an identity function.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much better than my helper class!