# Kotlin: use an object's property as "object value" instead of the object reference (like the Int object does)

Tags: kotlin, integer

For serializing/deserializing purposes, I have special classes like `UInt16` which internally represents a `UShort` Kotlin data type. This class has special methods for deserializing it from resp. serializing it into a `ByteBuffer`.

```kotlin
class UInt16(val name: String) {
    var value: UShort? = null

    fun writeTo(buffer: ByteBuffer) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw Exception("no value for field $name defined, cannot serialize it")
        }
        value?.let { buffer.putShort(it.toShort()) }
    }

    fun getFrom(buffer: ByteBuffer) {
        value = buffer.short.toUShort()
    }
}
```

This way, I can do something like:

```kotlin
val a: UInt16
a.getFrom(buffer)
println("The value of a is: ${a.value}")
```

Now I am asking myself if it is possible to just use `a` for getting/setting the (internal) value instead of `a.value`. It should be possible because the `Int`, `UShort` and all other basic data types work this way, don't they? In other words, the "value" of the object itself should not be a reference to the object, but should be the value of the property `value`.

How can I nail the "public representation" to the property `value`, but still have the methods like `getFrom` at hand.

I would love to do something like this:

```kotlin
val a: UInt16
a.getFrom(buffer)
println("The value of a is: $a")
val b = a * 3
println("b is $b")
```

or do this:

```kotlin
val another: UInt16 = 5000
```

instead of having to do this:

```kotlin
val another: UInt16
another.value = 5000
```

Comment: Syntactically, I don't think you can do this. There are no implicit conversions in Kotlin. But this is possible at the bytecode level by using [value classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html). By "bytecode level" I mean that the `.value` access won't be visible from the generated bytecode. From the bytecode, it would seem as if you are just operating on a `Short`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586813/5133585) for an example.

Comment: By the way, what do you expect `another.name` to be, when you do `val another: UInt16 = 5000`?